# How to connect to express api deployed on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two services deployed on a project

1. default
2. api

**1. default** - Service running the react app

**2. api** - Service running the express app

I have a dispatch yaml the routes request incoming to either of the two services

```
dispatch:
   url: 'xx.com/*'
   service: default

   url: 'api.xx.com/*'
   service: api
```

I cannot seem to make any requests to the api. 
The error that I'm hitting constantly is

`POST https://api.xx.com/register net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Could you please add the structure of your project? and how you deploy? 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#deploying_the_dispatch_file

Comment: I understand that you *are* able to access the  default service.